# Can I take GRE year prior to applying graduate schools?

Tags: application, professorship, gre

I will be taking GRE this November 2015 (giving four colleges name whose application I will fill fall 2016) , but will start the application process by next year. Will the college keep my GRE score for fall applications of 2016.?.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I took the GRE general exam several years before applying for grad school and that was no problem. ETS, which produces the GRE, keeps records forever. The school, however will probably not, at least not automatically.

You could ask the school to look for them, but run the risk of getting the admin grumpy. I'd only advise that option if paying the $27 fee for ETS to send scores again is financially difficult, in which case i'd make sure the university admission understands that.

See here for more details from ETS:
http://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/scores/send/asr

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question defers university-wise, but the general outcome is that universities will not record your GRE scores, unless you apply for them and pay the application fee.

In the later case, you can ask them to transfer your application with documents already in their position (including GRE score) to the next semester/year.

However, I strongly encourage you to get in contact with the graduate admissions office of each university before filling any application and paying the fee. Without paying application fee, still there might be a slight chance that you will be able to have them keep the score for a year. Good luck on your GRE exam.